# Is it possible to use Ninject with a static property?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, static, properties, ninject

I have a static `SessionFactory` class that initializes an NHibernate session factory. Because this process is expensive (~5 sec.), I want it to be static so it's only done once, at the beginning of runtime.

The configuration can take a database parameter parameter like so:

```
public static IPersistenceConfigurer DbConfig { get; set; }

public static void Initialize()
{
    var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
                      .Database(DbConfig)
                      .Mappings(some mappings)
                      .BuildConfiguration();
}
```

Is it possible to use Ninject to inject DbConfig with the correct constant?

Comment: I don't use NInject, but caching as a singleton is what you want instead of making it static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making this static, register the ISessionFactory instance (`ToConstant()`) then register the ISession with a request scope (`InRequestScope`)

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/57297224da1d01b8/2ad9044bd1471a2b?#2ad9044bd1471a2b) explains it quite clearly.